# Pairing Bluetooth devices programmatically

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I use this method to pair a device with an android cell phone:

```
private void pairDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
    try {
        device.getClass().getMethod("setPairingConfirmation", boolean.class).invoke(device, true);
        device.getClass().getMethod("cancelPairingUserInput").invoke(device);
        Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createBond", (Class[]) null);
        m.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error on pairing devices", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I checked it in three devices. On of the has 4.2.2 version of android and the other two devices use 4.4.2  version of android.

The `pairDevice` method works properly on those two 4.4.2 devices. However it gives `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException` error on 4.2.2 device. All three devices have Bluetooth V4 (v4.0, A2DP, LE according to their specifications).

I make visible and discoverable all devices before pairing them. Also I do not  want to connect my device to multiple cell phone at the same time.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Which line is throwing the exception? Most likely some method is missing. Why don't you try to cast to detect which API is available?

Comment: This line: m.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);

Comment: `Toast` the actual classname, device.getClass().getName(), and find that class in the API Level 17 (4.2). Then find the proper signature for `createBond()` or similar method.

Comment: why wouldn't use the BluetoothAdapter class?

Comment: I've used BluetoothAdapter class to find out about bluetooth state and paired devices. How could I use BluetoothAdapter to pair devices???

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,its work for me.

```
  private void pairDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
            try {
                Method method = device.getClass().getMethod("createBond", (Class[]) null);
                method.invoke(device, (Object[]) null);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```